# password_verify() in php returns false for correct password

Tags: php, hash

Here is the register.inc.php

```html
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
$error_msg = "";

sec_session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['contactno'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['inviteid']
    )) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'contactno', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lastname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $inviteid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inviteid', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'address', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error"  style="color:red; font-size:16px;>* The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }
 
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error"  style="color:red; font-size:16px;>* Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

 
    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //
 
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
 
   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
 
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error"  style="color:red; font-size:16px;">* A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error"  style="color:red; font-size:16px;>* Database error Line 39</p>';
                $stmt->close();
    }
 
    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
 
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
 
                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                        // A user with this username already exists
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error" style="color:red; font-size:16px;">* A user with this username already exists</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error"  style="color:red; font-size:16px;>* Database error line 55</p>';
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE myid = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
 
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['inviteid']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
 
                if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
                        // A user with this us
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error" style="color:red; font-size:16px;">* No user with this id exists</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error"  style="color:red; font-size:16px;>* Database error line 55</p>';
        $stmt->close();
    }
               //1.86€y9.31€$Ac2w6xufmG.jI3F/5GZhDOdW1TzAPrnJ3oPF0seGHI6g03QopB4C

        // TODO: 
        // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
        // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
        // perform the operation.
     
        if (empty($error_msg)) {
            // Create hashed password using the password_hash function.
            // This function salts it with a random salt and can be verified with
            // the password_verify function.

            $passwords = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
     
            // Insert the new user into the database 
            if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password,firstname,lastname,phone,address,inviteid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $username, $email, $passwords, $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $address, $inviteid);
                // Execute the prepared query.
                if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                    header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
                }
            }
             /*if (login($_POST['email'],$_POST['p'], $mysqli) == true) {
                    // Login success 
                    header('Location: dashboard.php');
                }else{
                    // Login failed 
                    //header('Location: login.php');
                }  */
            // header('Location: dashboard.php');
             //exit();
        }
}

?>
```

process_login.php

```html
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
include_once '../securimage/securimage.php';

//$securimage = new Securimage(); 
sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.
 
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

        if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Login success 
            //        header("Location: ../protected_page.php");
            header('Location: ../dashboard.php');
        }else{
            // Login failed 
            header('Location: ../login.php?error=1');
        }    

} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    header('Location: ../error.php?err=Could not process login');
    exit();
}
```

Hi there I am trying to hash my passwords with password_hash() in PHP. This part is fine but to compare the hash is returning false no matter what. To log in I check the user account database and grab the password hash then compare it to the password typed in.Have checked all solutions here.
 My code looks like this:

```html
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, myid, firstname, lastname,status,ambLevel
        FROM members
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();


        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $myid, $fname, $lname, $status, 
            $ambLevel);
        $stmt->fetch();

        var_dump($db_password);
        var_dump($password);

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted. We are using
                // the password_verify function to avoid timing attacks.
                if (password_verify($password,$db_password)) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value

                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $fname;
                    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lname;
                    $_SESSION['myid'] = $myid;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['status'] = $status;
                    $_SESSION['ambLevel'] = $ambLevel;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $db_password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please kindly help. View my full source code [here](https://github.com/tejumola/Eatrich%22Here%22).

Comment: It should work.. Just try it with some dummy values..

Comment: Its doesnt work with correct password.

Comment: The second parameter of `verify_password` should be `hash`, does it?
[password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: @Mohammad yes it the hashed password from the database after registering a new user

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected...

```
<?php

$hash=password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if (password_verify("password", $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and resolved it by setting the password column in my DB to a sufficiently long (255) VARCHAR instead of CHAR or NCHAR variable. If this doesn't help, try var_dump at all the transfer points: when first hashing, taking it from the database itself, and after submitting your query.